# Move object in inches instead of feet?

Tags: interface, units, measurement

Whenever I move an object in blender in unit mode(Imperial), it always make it in feet. For example, if I type <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>12</kbd>, it will move 12 feet. **How can I make it move 12 inches instead?**

Comment: @cegaton I tried that, It didn't work

Comment: try typing the transform->loacation tab 12". that should work

Comment: @cgeaton No, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iqhpb.gif

Comment: @cgceaton, No I don't wan't to do that, its annoying going in & out of that pannel... Also, I have to work out based on the previous location.

Comment: G Y 1 will give you one foot (12")... I've never liked imperial...

Comment: I just type [3], ["]  and it moves it 3 inches.

Comment: Didn't work, I tried G - Y - 12 "

Comment: The point is, shouldn't I be able to type the vale in inches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When performing any action (such grabbing) that has a number input during the modal operator; you must first press <kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>NumPad *</kbd> to enable [advanced input](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI#Transform_Tools_Number_Input) for the units.
By default the number input for the modal operators is set to *simple*, that is why typing in any units after the value does not work.

I would highly suggest everybody reads the [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI#Transform_Tools_Number_Input) for the number input feature

Comment: Yes, I knew it has to be possilble

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Like I said I had not figured this one out scene 2.70. Thank you for giving me the incentive to learn it.