# how do you spin-duplicate an object to make a grenade?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I ma making a grenade like this one in the image:
[image]

And I have the main bumpy part here:
[image]

so I want to spin them to make that shape, but nothing seems to work.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-use-array-to-create-circular-array-without-spiralling

Comment: already viewed those. I can't get that kind of thing to work. Here is the blend file if you want to check it out: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz8mi5dxj4l3t8d/grenade.blend.zip?dl=0]

Answer (score 1):

As Sandro suggested: the objects scaling (marked in the image) causes the - in this case (as Kheetor mentioned) - undesired outcome.
Your object is scaled to about 45% of it's original size, so every iteration of the array is scaled to a 45% again, getting smaller and smaller every time.
Select the object and press 'ctrl+a', then select 'Scale'.
[image]

Next Step: Your object and the "rotation object" need the same origin. Go into edit-mode and move all geometry to the edge of the circle:
[image]

Then just rotate your circle around the Z-axis:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but there's something you could be more specific about. Scaling doesn't exactly "mess with the array", rather the array modifier with object offset takes into account the entire transform: location, rotation and scale. If you have any difference in location, rotation OR scale, the new instances generated by array are going to have all this difference affecting them, it is an intended feature of the array modifier that you could make use of.

Comment: You are correct, sir. And I have to admit I already used this intended behaviour. I edited the answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

tried it with your file and got it to work:

First I deleted circle and ring. You don't need them.
Your problem was, that you did'nt apply scale/rotation/location. If I had to bet on I would say scale was your problem. Thats why your array objects got bigger and bigger.
Apply those, use an empty in your array modifier as object offset, and rotate it around it's z axis.

If you have further questions or need a more detailed description feel free to ask ;)

Comment: think that detailed explanation would help. I tried it but I got some weird result (it won't let me put a screen shot on the comments?).

Comment: Thanks guys! All these comments really helped. I think it turned out great! Please tell me what you think of it: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5mq6qg3488zjjy/grenades_01%20copy.jpg?dl=0]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but...

You can start from a sphere to do that directly:

- Choose the good amount of segments / rings
- In edit mode select the wanted faces and extrude individual faces <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
- Choose pivot center to be individual origins and scale down the extruded faces
- Refine scaling Z the whole sphere and for instance add some bevel

[image]