# Can't make circular array around an empty

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a circular array of objects around an empty, as most tutorials suggest however whenever I do this I get a load of weird random sized objects appearing.

It looks like the dimensions of the initial object changes to random large numbers and when I try to change them manually they just increase to even bigger numbers.

I thought this might be a bug in v2.78 so I uninstalled and got v2.79b but it still does the same thing. Here is a before and after selecting the empty as the object offset.

[image]

[image]

Comment: make sure you have applied all transforms to all objects including Scale. CTRL+a

Comment: you must have scaled your empty, if it's your problem apply the scale and instead change it in the Properties panel > Data > Display > Size. But maybe share your file?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm very new to this. If you can look at the file I would be grateful. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CF5qq1pQU9yjh4Co7l5p20AZXqU_Ds6v

Comment: I read your question, went away from the computer, came back and took the computer out of standby, and the following was open on my screen. No idea where or why it came (from) but it seems relevant?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-use-array-to-create-circular-array-without-spiralling

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Susan! This will probably be an easier method to use in the future however I am still getting the same problem. https://imgur.com/a/FuueBCI I have tried the transform thing and made sure all the boxes are ticked but it is not making any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed the point of your question, or not understood what exactly you wanted to do, but ...

Ignore the empty and don't activate offset. Put the 3D cursor in the centre of the world (0,0,0)

Create a Bezier Circle

In the cylinder's modifier, change Fixed Count to Fit Curve.  Choose the Bezier Circle as the curve.

You'll get a vertical array of however many cylinders you need to fit the circumference of that circle.

With the Array selected, assign a new modifier - Curve - and choose the Bezier Circle as the curve.  I had to set the **axis to Z** to get what you see in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have some object-level transforms hidden away in the Properties > Object > Delta Transforms panel of the disc. Those aren't baked into the mesh with an 'Apply' operation. Clear those, and the behavior of the Object Offset in the array modifier will be more predictable.