# How can I use the Array modifier correctly?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I want this

[image]

This is my screen.
version is 2.90.1
What's wrong with the array modifier?

Comment: Place the cube origin at the location of the empty

Comment: ah thank you so much !   :)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-use-array-to-create-circular-array-without-spiralling

Comment: thank you so much :) it is best impormation